# Get a CGImageRef from an IKImageView in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, ikimageview

I'm trying to get the image associated with a view but Xcode returns me an error. Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: IKImageView // Link to the image view.

func saveImage() {
    var newImage: CGImageRef = imageView.image() // Line with an error.
}
```

I have a `awakeFromNib`function to set the image in the view. The code above returns me `'Unmanaged<CGImage>' is not convertible to 'CGImageRef'`.

I know that types are optional in Swift but I don't understand why I get this error, the [IKImageView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageView/IKImageView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/IKImageView/image) clearly said that get IKImageView's image return a CGImageRef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the bridging of Objective C APIs into Swift. The Swift versions of an API have been bridged (mostly automatically, I believe) by converting the original Objective C headers into a Swift version. In many cases, the conversion can work out what kind of value you're going to get back, and therefore in Swift you get a "normal" type that you can use as you'd expect.

However, the conversion is still a work in progress. In this case, what you're seeing is a type used to help you manage memory manually when the conversion process doesn't know whether you're going to get back an object that's been retained for you or not, because the API doesn't have the conventional annotation that it could use to figure it out.

The `Unmanaged` type effectively says "you have to tell me what to do with the contained value to get the memory management right". As soon as you get an Unmanaged value, you should call either one of its two methods:

```
takeUnretainedValue() 
takeRetainedValue()
```

...depending on whether the object you get back was a "+0" or "+1". So, you're expected to do something like:

```
var newImage: CGImage = imageView.image().takeUnretainedValue()
```

And as soon as you've done that (which you should do pretty much immediately), you've given Swift enough of a hint that it can now appropriately manage the object correctly with ARC, and got yourself a valid reference of the right type.

This is touched on briefly at the end of the "Swift Interoperability in Depth" WWDC video from this year.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the useful WWDC video, the new line makes my app crashes (but no more errors before the build). I tried with `takeUnretainedValue()` and `takeRetainedValue()` just in case, do you think I should fill a bug report?

Comment: Depends on the crash, and where it is. Is it on the new line (which should be relatively safe, I think), or is it when you try to use the newImage? Is it possible that there's actually no image (i.e. `nil`) coming back from the `image()` call? Probably needs a bit more debugging.

Comment: `println(imageView.image().takeUnretainedValue())`returns `<CGImage 0x6080001a6740>`. The problem seems to be on the line when I set `newImage`.

Comment: Hrm. So you've definitely got what looks like a valid CGImage. And putting that into a CGImageRef (I'll change my answer to follow @rickster's advice and use CGImage in a sec) should be fine, as they're typealiases. What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: When do I use takeUnretainedValue() or takeRetainedValue()?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `image()` method in [the new version of the `IKImageView` reference that shows Swift declarations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/IKImageView/image) and you'll see it returns an `Unmanaged<CGImage>!`. That means that ImageKit isn't set up such that the compiler can automatically infer CoreFoundation memory management semantics on its API. (This affects both Swift translation and ObjC implicit ARC bridging.) It should, so that'd be [a good bug to file](http://bugreport.apple.com).

The Swift type `Unmanaged<T>` is how you interact with CF types when the compiler can't automatically infer their ARC behavior. To get at the underlying type, call either `takeUnretainedValue()` or `takeRetainedValue()` — you have to choose which depending on whether the API you're calling is known to already be retaining the value it returns. Exciting guesswork! (Again, eliminating guesswork would be [a good bug to file](http://bugreport.apple.com).) You can read more about this in [*Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_50).

Anyway, in this case you can probably expect that `IKImageView` is not incrementing the retain count of the `CGImage` when providing it, so you can unwrap the `Unmanaged` like so:

```
var newImage: CGImage = imageView.image().takeUnretainedValue()
```

Also note you don't need the `Ref` suffix when working with CF types in Swift. (`CGImageRef` is a typealias to `CGImage`.) Swift lets you work with CF types as if they're Swift objects (instead of as C pointers to opaque C types).